# How can I integrate Python rosunit unit tests into the cmake build?

Tags: ros, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run `rosunit` Python unit tests as part of `make test` in the CI environment. In the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#Running_tests_as_part_of_.27make_test.27.2BAC8-CMakeLists.txt) and in the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_nose_configuration.html) it is recommended to use `cmake_add_nodetest()` for that. Is `cmake_add_nosetest()` specific to `nosetest` or can it used with the plain `unittest` test runner as well/instead? (I know that `rosunit` depends on `unittest`. I didn't recognize a dependency from `nosetest`.) If it's possible: Could you guide me to an integration example in the ROS code base?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273103/how-can-i-integrate-python-rosunit-unit-tests-into-the-cmake-build?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nosetest is a test runner. It will collect and run detected unittest test cases found in the test files.  See: https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-17**:
Sorry, my question is not precise enough. I was interested in if I can use only `nosetest` 's test runner or any other as well (e.g. the one of `unittest`).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-18**:
It's likely you could add integration for it but it's not currently supported.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-19**:
Ok. If I would like to add integration where in the sources I should dive into first?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-19**:
I would look inside catkin and make a parallel function like catkin_add_nosetests: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake